# While checking out, PayPal displays merchant name as test store at sandbox environment.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an issue regarding the PayPal integration to my application. 
While paying with PayPal the server redirects me to the payment page, and asks for the credentials, on that page the title shows as "the combination of First name and last name + 's Test store". 
Now I have a confusion regarding this, does this actually displays First name and last name over there? Is it so then how to change this setting to display merchant name?
Also when I will go live with this does the test store will remove?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the business name on the merchant account. It will be located in the "Business Information" section of the account profile.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I have already added business information to that  section. Would it be reflect to transaction page only after going live?

Comment: My apologies, the solution above works on live accounts; the sandbox may not pass that field to the hosted page.

Comment: So you mean that after going live the site will automatically replace the test names with business name? Or do we need to do any additional configuration?

Comment: It should automatically display your current business name when you go live.